# Error:Execution failed for task .DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, runtime

I am getting error Unable to merge dex

that’s my gradle

I have already done following

clean and rebuild
Invalidate and restart
multiDexEnabled true
implementation ‘com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1’
Delete .gradle folder and restart android studio
Still problem is not resolved I am stuck from 2 days please help

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: post your gradle.app code

Comment: If you have modules in app, make sure all modules have same support version, Had similar use & this solution helped me.

Comment: This error happens when you add an external library which may not be compatible with your compiled version. Be careful when you are adding an external library. Plz, provide app:build.gradle file then we can give an answer to this

Answer (score 0):

Android has recently updates their libraries into `27.1.0`,So simply change your dependencies.

Also add this in `app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```